# I'm trying to close several opened layer popups in sequence with esc. What should I do?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to close several opened layer popups in sequence with esc. What should I do?

The currently applied source is as follows. When you press esc on the keyboard, it is clicked on the close button of the layer popup to close it.

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.key == "Escape") $('.window .close').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe like this?? I can't see all the code so this might work

```js
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.key == "Escape") $('.close').click();
  $('your_popup_ids').hide();  / / you can also use .toggle
});
```